# How to get rid of a shared folder on Mac

Tags: finder, macos, sharing

How to remove **Shared** folder with **bsozasss** files? I somehow got this from my second PC and have no idea how and what this is? How can I remove this and disable this kind of sharing? I am on El Capitan.

Here is the screenshoot:

[image: folder]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a Finder window, then open preferences (Finder > Preferences...). Go to the 'Sidebar' tab and uncheck the options under 'Shared':

[image]

If you want to make sure *your* computer doesn't appear on *other* computers like this, go to System Preferences > Sharing and uncheck File Sharing:

[image]

Comment: Note that turning off the "Shared" options in Finder preferences doesn't really turn off any sort of sharing. "bsozasss" is another computer on your network, and it has some sort of file (or screen) sharing turned on; after turning off the Finder option, it'll still be on your network and still offering to share files and/or its screen, it's just that your Finder will stop showing it in the sidebar.